# In writing an R package, using the flowCore::transform function, can I both use a variable name as text and get the actual value?

Tags: r, bioconductor, scoping, rlang, quosure

I am trying to pass on an argument to a function, which is a string but must be evaluated both for it's name (symbol?) and it's value (see example below). So far I am able to use `base::get` to get the actual value, but the assignment in `flowCore::'transform,flowSet-method'` fails.
I am aware that many questions on SO are on evaluating strings as variable names and, as you will see below I tried a whole lot of them. I assume there must be an `rlang` based answer, but I cannot find any solution, any pointers would be appreciated.

A reproducible example:

```
# load required packages -------------------------------------------------------
library(flowAI)   # Bioconductor
library(flowCore) # Bioconductor
library(rlang)
# load example data ------------------------------------------------------------
data(Bcells) # from flowAI
# reprex -----------------------------------------------------------------------
timeCh <- "Time" # this could be variable

x <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,`Time`=(`Time`-min(`Time`)))           # this works
y <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,`Time`=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh)))) # still good
z <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,timeCh=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh)))) # not good
```

While in the code above the transform for `z` will run just fine, in fact a new column is added to the flowSet called "timeCh". This is not the desired effect, because I want to use the transform to specifically change the existing column `Time`. Hence, I have been trying a few strategies to evaluate the string stored in timeCh as an object name (?) into `transform`, but to no avail:

```
timeSym <- sym("Time")
timequo <- quo(timeCh)

t1 <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,!!timeSym=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh)))) 
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t1 <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,!!timeSym="
t2 <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,{{timeSym}}=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t2 <- flowCore::transform(Bcells,{{timeSym}}="
t3 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,eval(parse(text=timeCh))=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t3 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,eval(parse(text=timeCh))="
t4 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,assign(timeCh,(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh)))))
# Error in get(timeCh) : object 'Time' not found
t5 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,assign(timeCh,(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))),inherits = TRUE))
# Error in get(timeCh) : object 'Time' not found
t6 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,with(Bcells,assign(timeCh,(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))),inherits = TRUE)))
# Error in get(timeCh) : object 'Time' not found
t7 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,as.name(timeCh)=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t7 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,as.name(timeCh)="
t8 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,UQ(timequo)=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t8 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,UQ(timequo)="
t9 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,(eval(quote(timeCh)))=(get(timeCh)-min(get(timeCh))))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "t9 <-  flowCore::transform(Bcells,(eval(quote(timeCh)))="
```

It seems to me an issue with scoping, but I am really stumped on how to get around it.

Comment: I could probably show you how to do this with computing on the language but I'm not willing to install Bioconductor packages for this. Can you create a reproducible example that only needs CRAN packages?

Comment: @Roland: I am willing to provide a dataset outside of flowAI, but as the issue is on `flowCore::'transform,flowSet-method'`, it would be pretty essential for me that it could be evaluated within that context (the `flowCore` class `flowSet`).

Answer (score 5):

One possible way using `rlang` expression arithmetic:

```
# Compose the expression `Time = Time - min(Time)`
tfarg <- rlang::exprs( !!timeSym := !!timeSym - min(!!timeSym) )

# Compose the expression `flowCore::transform(Bcells, Time = Time - min(Time))`
xpr  <- rlang::expr( flowCore::transform(Bcells, !!!tfarg) )
xpr2 <- rlang::call2( flowCore::transform, Bcells, !!!tfarg )   # Alternative

# Evaluate the second expression
t1 <- eval(xpr)      # or t1 <- eval(xpr2)

# Compare to desired output
identical( summary(t1), summary(x) )  # TRUE
```

In the above, we first create the expression `Time = Time - min(Time)` using [quasiquotation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html). Think of it as replacing `!!timeSym` with the symbol stored inside `timeSym` (i.e., `Time`), while using `:=` to make it work on the left-hand side of the assignment.

We then create the second expression `flowCore::transform(Bcells, Time = Time - min(Time))` by pasting the first expression inside a `flowCore::transform()` function call. Lastly, we evaluate it and compare the result to your desired output.

**Side note:** it appears that the minimum Time value is zero, so your `transform()` effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this function basically mimics `base::transform` and its non-standard evaluation. That means I can use this as a MRE:

```
expectedresult <- transform(airquality, Ozone = Ozone - min(Ozone))
```

First we rewrite this using `do.call`:

```
all.equal(
  do.call(transform, list(`_data` = airquality, Ozone = quote(Ozone - min(Ozone))))
  ,expectedresult)
#[1] TRUE
```

Great, now we can set the list names programmatically and substitute into the quoted expression:

```
varname <- "Ozone"
varsymbol <- as.name(varname)

all.equal(
  do.call(transform, 
          setNames(list(airquality, bquote(.(varsymbol) - min(.(varsymbol)))), 
                   c("_data", varname)))
  ,expectedresult)
#[1] TRUE
```

Let me finish with some advice:

Try to avoid convenience functions that rely on non-standard evaluation if they make such gymnastics necessary in your code.